# C# application publishing error - references to development computer in cronjob errors on remote dev server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cron, environment-variables, publishing

I have written a C# program, published it using visual studio to a folder on my computer(windows), and FTPed those files onto a remote dev server(linux), where they run fine. The program runs manually  without issue, but it will not run from the cronjob I have set up. The strange part is what I see in the cron errors output:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Required Environment Variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is missing or was not specified
   at MyProgram.Startup.LoadConfiguration() in C:\Users\Developer\source\repos\LargerProject\MyProgram\Startup.cs:line 31
   at MyProgram.Startup.ConfigureServices() in C:\Users\Developer\source\repos\LargerProject\MyProgram\Startup.cs:line 45
   at MyProgram.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Developer\source\repos\LargerProject\MyProgram\Program.cs:line 13
/opt/dotNetCore/MyProgram/ExecutionScript.sh: line 3:  1418 Aborted
```

the body of the execution script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILEPATH=/opt/dotNetCore/ProgramData/Program_data.csv
dotnet /opt/dotNetCore/Program/Program.dll $FILEPATH
```

cronjob:

```
0,29 * * * * /opt/dotNetCore/Program/ExecutionScript.sh 2> /tmp/ScriptLog.txt 2>&1
```

ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set up as a variable on the dev box, and is picked up when the ExecutionScript is run manually.

As you can see there are references to the development machine(C:\Users\Dev...) that the dev box is finding somehow. I would have thought these would be removed by publishing the program. Do I need to publish to the remote machine to avoid this, or is it likely this is some error in my publishing settings?

I have assumed this is an issue with the publishing of the app but if you have other ideas I'd like to hear them.

Comment: Could it be that you published a debug version? Those will contain source code information. Can you share your cron script? It seems that the error is more in that area than in how you published the app

Comment: This "references" are just metadata/debugging information and just pointing the source file... The real error is *Required Environment Variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is missing or was not specified*

Comment: Could it be that you've setup the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable as user scoped?

Comment: I think both of these points are correct. It looks as though I may have published debug and that's why I'm getting the odd references, and it seems like cron doesn't neccesarily pick up environment variables, and needs to be told where to get them. I'll investigate.